# Обновить элемент в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как обновить элемент `HelloWorld` из функции `updateHelloWorld` и вообще это возможно?

Пример кода:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

function getServerData() {
  // Получаем данные с сервера 
  data = new GetServerData() 
  return data.data
}

function updateHelloWorld() {
   // Магия которая должна обновить элемент 
} 

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello world  {getServerData}</h1>
    );
  }
}

class ButtonClisk extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateHelloWorld}>Обновить</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <HelloWorld />
    <ButtonClisk />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Можно сделать проще, через `setState`. Но вот в вопросе не совсем понятно, что нужно обновить

Comment: @DenisBubnov обновить элемент `<HelloWorld />` и не обновлять все приложение то есть без обновления `<ButtonClisk />`

Comment: Ваш копонент `ButtonClisk` ничего не знает про компонент `HelloWorld` - это первое. Второе - я до сих пор не понял, что вы хотите там обновить. Думаю, вам нужно немного почитать про React и [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Чтобы  вы понимали, как компоненты могут взаимодействовать друг с другом и как их обновлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно, но делаете вы это не правильно.

Вот простейший пример реализации, более подробно лучше почитать в учебниках. Попробуйте [этот](https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/react-course-ru/content/) или [этот](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/react) для начала, оба на русском языке.

```js
// Получаем данные с сервера
// допустим, это какой-то сервер или библиотека, которую вы подключаете в своём проекте
function getServerData() {
  return 'SERVER DATA: ' + new Date();
}

// это может быть функция, которая вызывается в экшене (если использовать редакс)
function updateHelloWorld() {
  const serverData = getServerData();
  console.log('data:', serverData);
  return serverData;
} 

// первый дочерний компонент
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div>
        { data ?
          data :
          <h1>Hello world</h1>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// второй дочерний компонент
class ButtonClick extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Обновить</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// родительский компонент
// он хранит в себе состояние и реагирует на событие/передаёт полученные данные нужному компоненту 
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: '' };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    const data = updateHelloWorld();
    this.setState({ data: data });
  }
  
  render() {
    const data = this.state.data;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* данные передаются через пропсы */}
        <HelloWorld data={data} />
        {/* обработчик также передаётся через пропсы */}
        <ButtonClick onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ и за ссылки на ресурсы, появилось понимания архитектуры React приложений.